# Найти последний самый акутальный файл в списке

Tags: c#

Никак не могу представить в головке функцию, которая бы обходила файлы сравнивая их имена с `DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1).ToShortDateString().ToString()`
И если не находила, то уменьшала число в AddDays ещё на один.
Есть список файлов, который я извлекаю из папки. Все файлы там имеют имена в виде дат(но это не значит, что они загружались именно тогда) 13.12.2018.* - например. Представим, что сейчас самый последний там 5.12.2018. Как извлечь имя самого последнего файла, сравнивая его с маской. Я понимаю, что это должен быть перебор сравнения файлов через форич, и если все результаты фолс - уменьшить ещё на день и повторить.

Comment: Почему бы не отсортировать список файлов по ключу-дате?

Comment: Так не получится, т.к. файлы будут сортировать по группам сначала dd, потом mm, потом YYYY. Пример: 05.10.2018, 05.11.2018, 05.12.2018, 06.10.2018 и т.д. не факт, что последний в списке - самая поздняя дата.

Comment: Я же не зря про ключ сортировки написал - из названия нужно создать правильный ключ - например, преобразовав строку в дату, а не сортировать, как строки

Answer (score 3):

Алгоритм мне видится следующий:

1. извлечь имена файлов в список
2. распарсить дату из имени файла
3. отсортировать по этой дате в обратном порядке
4. выбрать первый элемент

А вот код попробуйте написать сами )

UPD:

> А, всё-таки, как будет тогда выглядеть такая сортировка?

```
var lastFileByName = Directory
   .GetFiles(@"C:\temp\", "*.zip")
   .Select(f =>
   {
       DateTime date;
       var n = new FileInfo(f).Name.Replace(".zip", string.Empty);
       return DateTime.TryParseExact(n, "d.M.yyyy", null, DateTimeStyles.None, out date)
           ? new {Date=date, FileName = f}
           : null;
   })
   .Where(it=> it != null)
   .OrderByDescending(it => it.Date)
   .FirstOrDefault()?
   .FileName;
```

Comment: Так не получится, т.к. файлы будут сортировать по группам сначала dd, потом mm, потом YYYY. Пример: 05.10.2018, 05.11.2018, 05.12.2018, 06.10.2018 и т.д. не факт, что последний в списке - самая поздняя дата.

Comment: распарсить дату означает выделить из текста и перевести ее в формат DateTime.

Comment: Но так и понял зачем парсить дату, да и сортировка дат в любом случае будет иметь вид - сравнить весь список с примером, если false уменьшить пример на 1 день, повторить. Для этого рапарсивать дату не обязательно.

Comment: @ВладЧекунаев зачем _сравнивать весь список с примером_ каждый раз уменьшая дату, если файл с самой большой датой в имени и будет искомым файлом ? И Ваш вариант тоже рабочий

Comment: А, всё-таки, как будет тогда выглядеть такая сортировка?             
 `DateTime[] dtArray;` и `dtArray.Max();`?

Comment: @ВладЧекунаев добавил в ответ linq-вариант

Answer (score 0):

самое простое это вот это. Можно же получить дату создания и  изменения файла

```
DateTime creation = File.GetCreationTime(@"file");
DateTime modification = File.GetLastWriteTime(@"file");
```

ну и потом отсоритрвоать даты как вам угодно

как то так

```
 string [] fileEntries = Directory.GetFiles(targetDirectory);

 foreach (var d in fileEntries )
 {
     dates.Add(File.GetLastWriteTime(d));
 }



var result = dates.Order(v => v).Last();
```

Comment: есть уточнение от автора : "но это не значит, что они загружались именно тогда"

Comment: ну  я отбираю по дату модицикации думаю это будет более актуально

Comment: вопрос не про дату же был,а про имя файлов по сути

Comment: да но как я понимаю имя файла содержит дату

Comment: Такой вариант я не рассматриваю, т.к. файлы были загружены абы как, несколько раз пеерзаписаны. Самый свежий сейчас от 09.10.2018. Он как раз был загружен и отредактирован. А файлы отсутствуют с 5.12.2018, так что такой вариант не подходит.

Answer (score 0):

Видимо проблема в том, что ты не знаешь, как парсить дату.

```
string fileName = "5.9.2018";
DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(fileName, "d.M.yyyy", null);
```

Вообще можно было бы про это и задавать вопрос.

Comment: Честно говоря, даже не знал, что можно собрать массив дат, в которых был метод взять последнюю дату.

Answer (score 0):

Итог: сделал так, без парссинга даты:

```
DirectoryInfo directory = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\temp\");
var ffiles = directory.GetFiles();
string lastDate = "";
int t = 0;
bool check = false;
do
{
foreach (var filesdate in ffiles)
    {
    string inputDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(t).ToShortDateString().ToString();
    check = inputDate+".zip" == filesdate.Name;
    if (check)
        {
        lastDate = inputDate;
        break;
        }
    }
t = t - 1;
}
while (check != true);
```

Далее я уже использую lastDate